# Setting Pango.FontDescription from a Gtk.FontButton

Tags: gtk, vala, pango

In my preference dialog I have a Gtk.FontButton for the user to select a font, later I create a new Pango.FontDesciption from the get_font_name () string. The problem is that the size for the font is never set.

```
var font = new Pango.FontDescription ();
var font_name = Window.SETTINGS.get_string ("room-font");
font.from_string (font_name);
stdout.puts (@"Font: $font_name, Size: $(font.get_size())");
```

This prints `Font: Sans 12, Size: 0`.

The [documentation](http://valadoc.org/#!api=pango/Pango.FontDescription.from_string) for from_string says "SIZE is a decimal number (size in points) or optionally followed by the unit modifier "px" for absolute size." which would seem to indicate that the size in `Sans 12` is formatted wrong. But the [documentation](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.FontButton.get_font_name) for FontButton says "If you want to render something with the font, use this string with from_string".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pango.FontDescription.from_string()` is a static method; it returns a new `Pango.FontDescription`. It does not change `font`, so that still has the defaults, and the default size appears to be 0. (Why it is a static method and not a constructor is beyond me.)

Comment: I can not believe I missed that... Thank you.

Comment: It's a static method because `PangoFontDescription` is a boxed type, not an Object.